# Plug in my iPod and get message: Windows does not recognize this USB device

Tags: windows-vista, usb, ipod

iPod Touch: 8gb 2nd generation
OS: Windows Vista

I never had a problem syncing my iPod Touch with my computer in the past. All of a sudden today, whenever I plug it in, i get a message pop-up that Windows does not recognize this USB device.

I've tried rebooting my PC and resetting my iPod and trying multiple USB ports and even a different USB cable - no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try connecting it to an other PC and/or other systems with different OS like windows XP or windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your cable is OK (test another iPod or iPhone with the same cable).

Make sure your iPod is OK (test it in another computer).

Make sure your USB controller is OK (test the iPod and cable in all other USB ports on your computer).